# Select columns by related table and property

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Imagine you have 2 tables "article" and "article_manage", with a configuration like this:

`article:
id
title
private (boolean)`


`article_manage:
id
article_id
user_id`

I want for each user list all articles where "private" is false or if the user can manage the article.
What is the mysql query to return that?

Answer (score 0):

Just `JOIN` the two tables like this:

```
SELECT m.user_id, m.article_id
FROM article_manage as m
INNER JOIN article as a on m.article_id = a.article_id
WHERE a.private = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Join statement. The following will help the use of it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx